# JDBC - how much operation is safe to keep uncommited

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, connection

I have around 10-15 (pool managed) connections in a batch job. The connections isolation level is READ_UNCOMMITTED. My plan is to commit all the JDBC Connections at the end. Each connection would perform bulk insert of around 30000-45000 records.

How much operation is it safe to keep uncommitted. Is it related to Main Memory available in database server. What are other points to take into consideration.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28752 *For both standard update batching and Oracle update batching, Oracle recommends you to keep the batch sizes in the general range of 50 to 100. This is because though the drivers support larger batches, they in turn result in a large memory footprint with no corresponding increase in performance. Very large batches usually result in a decline in performance compared to smaller batches.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a short reading, I would conclude that most db supporting transaction, would use a Log Buffer File or Memory, to sustain how much transaction can be stored in a transaction. All un-committed record will be put into this buffer. They get flushed every time the transaction get committed (or rollback).

Some reading I did :

1. [MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19569/mysql-transaction-size-how-big-is-too-big) Based on file size.
2. [SQLServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365418.aspx) also based on file size.
3. [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams129.htm) Based on memory, number of cpu, and architecture (32 or 64)

Answer (score 1):

Using `READ_UNCOMMITTED` is a really bad idea. You're writing code that performs decisions based on information in the database that may be rolled back.

As for how long to wait before committing changes, you need to ask yourself some questions:

1. How many separate insert/update/delete statements are related, i.e. must either *all succeed* or *all fail*? Never commit in the middle of such a sequence of statements.
2. How many outstanding insert/update/delete statements are you prepared to loose in case of failure, e.g. program crash or power failure?
3. Commits need to wait for synchronization, so committing too often reduces performance. Coupled with question 2, how important is performance, i.e. how long dare you wait before committing in the name of performance?

The maximum size of a transaction, i.e. the number of uncommitted insert/update/delete statements, is indirectly controlled by the *configuration* of the database server. Uncommitted statements are usually stored in a *log*, and the size of that log is limited, if nothing else by the size of the harddisk.